# Can I always use a colon before an enumeration?

Tags: punctuation, colons

I can think of many examples where an enmuration helps in understanding the sentence. However, I am not sure whether it is correct to put a colon before each enumeration. So which of the following sentences is incorrect?

(a) The density function can be estimated using both: (i)... and (ii) ...

(b) The density function can be categorized into two categories: (i)... and (ii) 
...

(c) The properties of the density function are: (i)... and (ii) ...

(d) A function is called a density function whenever: (i)... and (ii) ...

(e) A function is called a density function if: (i)... and (ii) ...

Thanks

Comment: You certainly shouldn't use (i)...(2); eiether use (1)...(2) or (i)...(ii).

Comment: @ChrisH Oh you are right. This was a typo & a CopyPaste. But do you have an answer for my question?

Comment: I don't like to say "always" - hence no answer. I'm unlikely to enumerate only 2 items. Assuming you have more, personally I'd use a colon in b and c but probably not the others. That's not too say it's wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post from Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/formatting-vertical-lists?page=2) advises to only use a colon **[I]f your lead-in statement is a complete sentence, use a colon at the end to introduce your list.**

The Chicago Manual of Style website agrees in their [FAQ](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/VerticalListsBullets.html).

That seems to be a good ground rule unless you are writing for anyone who has a style guide. If you are writing for a big company or a university find out if there is a style guide defining such things.

Comment: Thanks!. So you mean that only (b) needs a colon?

Comment: @Shaki Exactly :)